# failing on creating a dynamic div to change size on click and back

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created a dynamic page with multiple divs, the divs size is set to 30% each, now I try to make a Jquery that allows you on every time you click to change the div size to 100% and back to 30% on reclicking the div, unfortunate my code is not working:

that is the current jquery I use:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $(".div").click(function() {
    if($(this).css("width") == "30%")
      $(this).css("width", "100%");
    else
      $(this).css("width", "30%");
  }); 
});
```

and that is the css for the div

```
.div{
    min-height:430px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 7px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    margin:10px;
    float:left;
    width: 30%;
    min-width: 300px;
    transition: width 1s;
}
```

any solutions guys?

Comment: `$(this).css("width") == "30%"` will be always `false`, since `css("width")` returns value in pixel

Comment: because $(this).css("width") will return 300px as you set min-width:300px;

Comment: @PranavCBalan well yes that makes sense, any ideas how to solve it indeed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

compare it with its parent width:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $(".div").click(function() {
    if($(this).outerWidth()==$(this).parent().width())
      $(this).css("width", "30%");
    else
      $(this).css("width", "100%");
  }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $(".div").click(function() {
    var parentWidth = $(this).parent().width()
    if($(this).css("width") == .3 * parentWidth)
      $(this).css("width", "100%");
    else
      $(this).css("width", "30%");
  }); 
});
```

So what is happening here is width: 100% is always equal to its immediate parent

Answer (score 0):

Use class to do this work. When div is clicked add or remove class of element.

```js
$("div").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("wide");
});
```

```css
div {
    width: 30%;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 5px;
    float:left;
    transition: width 1s;
    background: green;
}

.wide {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As `$(this).css("width")` it is always to retrieve a pixels value, then you should calculate the 30% of the container.

```
var pixels = $('container').css("width");
var pixelsNumber = (parseFloat(pixels) * 30) / 100;
```

And then compare with it:

```
if($(this).css("width") == pixelsNumber + "px")
    $(this).css("width", "100%");
else
    $(this).css("width", "30%");
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).css("width") == "30%"` will not work.

It will a Boolean.

Also `$("#yourElement").width()` will always be in integer even though it is specified in `%` in style properties.

Instead you can calculate the percentage value

```
var _childWidth = $('#yourElement').width();
var _parentWidth = $('#yourElement').offsetParent().width();
var _percent = (width/parentWidth)*100;
```

In this case you also need to look the `position` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Another simple way of solving your problem

```
<script>
        $('.div').click(function() {
            if ($(this).hasClass('hundred')) {
                $(this).removeClass('hundred');
            } else {
                $(this).addClass('hundred');
            }
        });
```

add this to your CSS

```
.hundred {
            width: 100%;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to do that is

Make a class-

```
.div-100{
  width:100%;
}
```

and then add Jquery

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

  $(".div").click(function() {
    $('.div').toggleClass('div-100');
  }); 
});
```

And here is working demo on [code pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ezOqrR)